# Flutter consistent spacing for List Tile elements

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[image: Inconsistent Spacing]

I have a ListView.Builder with ListTiles and I would like the spacing to be consistent across the data fields. The way I have it setup now is by using Spacers in between each element such as this:

```
return ListTile(
    title: Row(children: [
        Text(data[0]),
        Spacer(),
        Text(data[1]),
        Spacer(),
        Text(data[2])
    ])
);
```

I'm looking for a solution that will keep the spacing responsive without the spacing being inconsistent across the ListView.builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to set a width for the Text

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return ListTile(
    title: Row(children: [
        SizedBox(
        width: size.width/4,
        child: Text(data[0]),
         )
        Spacer(),
        Text(data[1]),
        Spacer(),
        Text(data[2])
    ])
);
```